# Fetch Steam API information to page

Tags: php, api

I have found a great Steam API from Valve them self and I wonder now how I can put the specific information one by one. Example: `$steam['response']['players']['personastate']`. It doesn't need to be that solution. I just typed something :)

The request will be like this one below:

```
{
    "response": {
        "players": [
            {
                "steamid": "{hidden}",
                "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
                "profilestate": 1,
                "personaname": "nhagyavi",
                "lastlogoff": 1317692549,
                "commentpermission": 1,
                "profileurl": "http:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/id\/nhagyavi\/",
                "avatar": "http:\/\/media.steampowered.com\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/avatars\/c2\/c25479aeea82f85eb1134bfcc8e064dcef1d361f.jpg",
                "avatarmedium": "http:\/\/media.steampowered.com\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/avatars\/c2\/c25479aeea82f85eb1134bfcc8e064dcef1d361f_medium.jpg",
                "avatarfull": "http:\/\/media.steampowered.com\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/avatars\/c2\/c25479aeea82f85eb1134bfcc8e064dcef1d361f_full.jpg",
                "personastate": 1,
                "realname": "Erik Edgren",
                "primaryclanid": "103582791429525632",
                "timecreated": 1106321372,
                "gameserverip": "217.163.23.35:7777",
                "gameextrainfo": "Red Orchestra 2: Heroes of Stalingrad",
                "gameid": "35450",
                "gameserversteamid": "90083758048089092",
                "loccountrycode": "SE",
                "locstatecode": "{hidden}",
                "loccityid": {hidden}
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like JSON. You need [json.decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$json_object=
file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/");

        $json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);
        //var_dump($json_decoded);
        echo $json_decoded->response->players[0]->lastlogoff;
```

Outputs

```
1317711877
```

Comment: Thanks but your example doesn't print out anything. How do I fetch content from another page like http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamids=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX with JSON?

Comment: @ErikEdgren Please can you provide a sample link? That one says unauthourized.

Comment: Sure. http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=A29E2CEA5FB3F1E97711909AB06771A0&steamids=76561197960435530

Comment: JSON is just the encoding, you can use file_get_contents() to obtain the remote data if allow_url_fopen is enabled (true in most cases), otherwise you can use CURL or go with some libraries to abstract it all for you. I often use Zend_Http_Client.

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeHuberdeau: I only got the print_r() working on the following code. How do I print out a specific data from this code? $json1 = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=A29E2CEA5FB3F1E97711909AB06771A0&steamids=76561197960435530");

$tree1 = json_decode($json1);
$tree1->response->players[0]->steamid;

echo '<pre>'; print_r($tree1); echo '</pre>';

Comment: @ErikEdgren You can now remove your steam ID! :P

Comment: @Mob: I'm from Sweden :P The Steam ID is linked from the Steam API-page.